# How do I prevent imap-mail.outlook.com-<GUID>.txt from consuming disk space?

Tags: mail.app

[Recently](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/405269/4395), my MacBook became unstable due to limited disk space caused largely by a single 330 GB text file

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Logs/Mail/imap-mail.outlook.com-<GUID>.txt
```

I have successfully deleted this file, but a mere day later this file is already nearly 1GB.

How do I prevent this file from growing so large?

Comment: Have you tried seeing what's inside it? [It might be utter gobbledegook or even binary, but there may be a hint.] I have literally nothing in that folder, though I steadfastly refuse to use IMAP for mail, preferring to stick with POP3, even though my mail-server is office365, an IMAP-based structure.

Comment: Logs are always safe to delete IMO  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389226/how-to-limit-size-of-gmail-imap-log-files/389248#389248

Comment: @Tetsujin It's just log stuff, as text.

Comment: Yes… but what is it logging? That may help discover why.

Comment: @Tetsujin All the mail accounts are logging. It all looks pretty benign and routine. Is there a Mail setting to prevent logging, perhaps?

Comment: @anki That's the answer: [just prevent them from accumulating in the first place](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389226/how-to-limit-size-of-gmail-imap-log-files/389248#389248).

Comment: Probably best to link this through as a duplicate then, for future searchers [How to limit size of Gmail IMAP log files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389226/how-to-limit-size-of-gmail-imap-log-files)

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, that's what I [just linked to](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405331/how-do-i-prevent-imap-mail-outlook-com-guid-txt-from-consuming-disk-space?noredirect=1#comment563071_405331).

Comment: Indeed - but my linking it as a close-vote now allows you to accept it as a dupe. Refresh the page if you don't see it.

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe.